# Song similar to opening seconds of One Republic's "Connection"

Tags: similar-artists

A few years ago there was a video compilation (from the site "Busty Adventures") with a song that was very similar to [One Republic's "Connection"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdClcgeEnh4) (but only the first 5 seconds).

Please listen to "Connection" song and you must hear it -- help me please I can't sleep if I don't remember.

Answer (score 2):

I instantly recognize a similarity to ["Paper Planes" by M.I.A](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewRjZoRtu0Y) when hearing the first few seconds of Connection.

It has the same pattern of a single note repeated over and over with pretty much the same speed, and near to the same pitch.